# Two variables are 100% the same, yet when compared in an if statement, nothing is executed

Tags: php

I have two strings. They are both very long, but I have used `echo` to display both of them prior. Not a single character is different. But when I put them in the `if` statement, nothing inside executes.

```
if ($arrayFromMySqliArrayFetch['code'] == $_POST['code']) { echo 'please work.'; }
```

Is something just flying over my head? I don't understand why nothing will get executed?

I have duplicated the `if` statement but with different internals. How would I even narrow down what is causing the problem if there shouldn't be one? :(

**Edit**

Thanks for everyone's help. FYI, the strings are both trimmed and all. Using `var_dump` I found out that one strings has 128 characters (what it should be), and one, the `$_POST` has 132. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you also check for invisible characters (spaces, line breaks, word joiners, etc.) or characters that can consist of multiple characters?

Comment: assign them to temporary string variables to ensure it's not a type concern?

Comment: @Gumbo - Yes. Trimmed, the string is generated by my script, so no word joiners or line breaks.

Comment: @drachenstern - Could you explain 'type concern'? I tried it and the var dumps still show different amounts of characters.

Comment: Does anyone think it could be the fact that the default PHP encoding is ISO-8859-1 and the ones on all my pages are UTF-8? I'm about to read about them now. Will return with results.

Comment: saying that if you cast them both to strings, then it's not trying to compare an object to a string, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the randomly generated characters was an ampersand. It caused the difference in string length. I forgot exactly why, but that was what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to better understand type of each variable.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. One is 128 characters and one is 132. I don't understand where the extra characters are coming from since they are identical.

Comment: @Tarik: Most likely those are invisible characters which have no printable glyphs associated with them. Depending on the web browser you are using to display the echoed values, these characters may be viewed as '?', or a box, or just nothing. It appears yours is using the latter and thus it appears the strings are identical.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try

if ('same' == 'same') { - does it execute? I'm guessing so?

Try trimming your values if (trim($val) == trim($val)) to make sure there is no whitespace too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `strcmp()` function to compare two strings, or even the === operator. See [this link](http://www.phpcatalyst.com/php-compare-strings.php) for more about string comparison in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) the strings and then compare:

```
 if (trim($arrayFromMySqliArrayFetch['code']) == trim($_POST['code']))
     echo 'please work.';
```

Sometimes due to leading or trailing spaces (which are not readily visible) this occurs.